# Athena DateDiff

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, datediff

I am trying to do what I think is a simple date diff function but for some reason, my unit value is being read as a column ("dd") so I keep getting a **column cannot be resolved** error

I am using AWS Athena

My code is this

```
SELECT "reservations"."id" "Booking_ID"
    , "reservations"."bookingid" "Booking_Code"
    , "reservations"."property"."id" "Property_id"
    , CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."created") AS date) "Created"
    , CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."arrival") AS date) "Arrival"
    , CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."departure") AS date) "Departure"
    , CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."modified") AS date) "Modified"
    , date_diff("dd", CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."created") AS date), CAST("from_iso8601_timestamp"("reservations"."arrival") AS date)) "LoS"
FROM
    "database".reservations
LIMIT 5;
```

I am trying to get the difference in days from the "created date" and "Arrival Date"

I have tried date_diff with DD,"DD","dd",dd,Day,day,"day" and i get the same error.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Athena is based on Presto.  See Presto documentation for [`date_diff()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_diff) -- the unit is regular `varchar`, so it needs to go in single quotes:

```
date_diff('day', ts_from, ts_to)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!

Comment: Also useful to note that you cannot sub anything like `'s'` for 'second` or `'d'` for day -- I was doing similar and that tripped me up since I'm so used to being able to sub in a single character in other dialects.

Comment: Thanks, @thleo. I had to use `'millisecond'` instead of `'ms'`.