# Trying to get a DATEDIFF function to add a column to calculate days between start_date and end_date

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, datediff

Have tried to get this right so i can get # of days between starting and ending dates with are timestamps.

Keep getting errors like:
line 4:24: mismatched input 'as'. expecting: ',',

What am I missing?

```
SELECT
CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date,
DATEDIFF (d,start_date AS DATE, end_date AS DATE)
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";

SELECT
CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date,
DATEDIFF (day,start_date AS DATE, end_date AS DATE)
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";

SELECT
CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date,
DATEDIFF (day,start_date, end_date)
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";
```

Comment: syntax error on line 4 (DATEDIFF); google it.

Comment: @KatH. Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Found a solution in a similar stackoverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58326786/athena-datediff

SELECT
DATE(start_date) AS start_date,
DATE(end_date) AS end_date,
date_diff('day',CAST("start_date" AS DATE), CAST("end_date" AS DATE)) AS campaign_length 
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table"

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Athena is based on (the old) PrestoDB.  It uses `date_diff()` rather than `datediff()`:

```
SELECT CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
       CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date,
       DATE_DIFF(day, start_date, end_date)
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't get an error, but didn't get any results in the results table either, its just blank and red exclamation mark on the Query Results tab

SELECT
CAST(start_date AS DATE) AS start_date,
CAST(end_date AS DATE) AS end_date,
DATE_DIFF(day,start_date, end_date)
FROM "test"."question_five_temp_table";